# Adding a switch to a water boiler

Tags: switches

I've got a water boiler I want to add a switch to. It has a rating of 120v 60Hz and 1000w. Would I need to find a switch that is capable of withstanding 1000w or is that irrelevant to the switch? Thanks!

Comment: Do you really believe that the power you want to switch may be irrelevant?

Comment: Isn't this site for questions like this? It seems that this is "on topic"(describe your situation and specific problem you're trying to solve). I was not "seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them". Intrigued because I thought the replies I got were more than helpful, giving me a great first impression of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 1kW at 120v means your boiler is drawing 8.33A of current:
1000W / 120V = 8.33A
so this is what the switch much be capable of handling continuously.

A 10A rating should be safe & 15A or more would be best.

This simplistic formula only works for 'simple' things which turn electricity into heat, not things like pumps & compressors.

Answer (score 0):

Switches will be rated either for DC specs, AC specs, or both. You can use a DC switch for AC and you can use an AC switch for DC. But you have to be careful, then. If you can find an AC switch rated for 10A at 120VAC, then you should be good.

One reason why it's important to be careful and notice the rating is that AC has zeroes in it, twice per AC cycle. The moment you choose to open or close the switch, with AC, is "random" relative to the cycle. But for example when you open the switch there will be an "arc" drawn out as the metal contacts open up. But very soon after, the AC cycle will hit one of those zeros (your load is resistive so both the current and voltage will hit the zero around the same moment) and the arc is extinguished as the ionized air dissipates. DC doesn't have any zeros. So switch AC ratings are usually higher than the DC rating for the same switch. I don't know how to uprate a DC switch for AC use and it's probably partly a matter of construction details. So it's best you search for and select a switch that is actually rated for AC use. That way, you can be sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

> Typically all you need is 1000/120V=8A or round up to a 10A switch rated for 120Vac. But for temp control a thermostat and a 10A relay. Heaters are essentially linear R with low reactance at 60Hz, with some small positive temp coefficient on Resistance.

### Other details for future reference.

All switches have resistance in mΩ and the temperature rise must be limited by the current \$I^2*R\$ meanwhile the voltage*current is just always a very small % of the load which is 1000W in your case.

Mechanical Relays or Switches, in fact, are more efficient than transistors but the tradeoff is speed and MTBF. A Relay can have a **current gain** at full load of 500~3000 depending on size.

Switches must consider if the load is inductive there will be an arc when opened for a period of time >L/R of load until holding current of gap is extinguished.  So these relays or switches are de-rated for DC inductive loads.

For capacitive loads a surge current when closed must be considered and thus zero-crossing switches are often considered like ZCS Triac.

For magnetic loads like large transformers, remanence can be stored from last shutoff and smart grid power switches use that memory of phase cutoff and remanence to reclose at the same phase to minimize magnetic saturation effects of core due to switching.

But for **heaters are just resistive loads** so current is linear and the simple variable, Irms for choosing a switch with Vrms rating.  MTBF is often demonstrated is strongly (log) determined by the amount of switching current and derated from >1e6 cycles of mechanical operation to 1e4 cycles at rated current using linear AC rated RMS current. Since the sinewave is almost triangle wave the average V or I is exactly 1/3 the peak and this correlates with a DC resistive load current at 1/3 the Ipk AC current for MTBF.

For MTBF reasons, reducing or "de-rating" the max current capacity of a switch or relay or transistor is necessary for high quality designs.  ( Ref OMRON site for technical details )